# Escaping backticks fails

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

Typing

```
\`foo\`
```

produces `foo` instead of the desired literal backticks. It appears correctly in the preview however.

Comment: Wait,     what?

Comment: It's hard to actually put literal backticks in when literal backticks can't be escaped :)

Comment: I can't get `\BACKTICKfoo\BACKTICK` to work properly either.

Comment: ``escaped backtick?`

Comment: OK, but where is this actually necessary?

Comment: It seams to work for \*italics*.

Comment: Perhaps even \**bold** \*\*double escaped**.

Comment: @Jeff, I was trying to give a link to the BACKTICK par BACKTICK operator in Haskell. I was unable to put the backticks in.

Comment: @All: there's an easier and prettier workaround, check my answer. Now you can write backticks inside any linktext (or any text for that matter)

Comment: I wish the answers had a "view source" option like Wikipedia has for protected pages.

Comment: @Andrew: click on the "edit x hours ago" link to view the post source.

Comment: Now this is the epitome of a "`meta`" discussion.

Comment: Oddly, backslash-escaped inline nested backticks seem to work properly in comments: `cd \`cat foo\`` but not in questions and [answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/29300/183358)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was an actual bug in early versions of the official Markdown Perl implementation

http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=7c443c9d037a8b657965aefcfba10824ff258ba2

Comment: By official Perl implementation, I assume you really mean original. Unless you consider [daringfireball.net](http://daringfireball.net) as a governing body for Markdown. There are actually quite a few [modules on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Markdown) with [Markdent](https://metacpan.org/module/Markdent) being one of the best designed, and easiest to modify to create a new dialect.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Markdown reference](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code):

> The backtick delimiters surrounding a code span may include spaces — one after the opening, one before the closing. This allows you to place literal backtick characters at the beginning or end of a code span

A single backtick in a code span: `` ` ``

A backtick-delimited string in a code span: `` `foo` ``

Comment: If you don't want the gray around the backticks, you can use HTML entities, explained below.

Answer (score 7):

Test:

```
\`foo`
```

`foo`

```
<code>`foo`</code>
```

`foo`

```
&#96;foo&#96;
```

`foo`

```
`&#96;foo&#96;`
```

`&#96;foo&#96;`

```
<code>&#96;foo&#96;</code>
```

`` `foo` ``

Nested backticks with backslash escapes:

```
`foo \`bar\``
```

`foo \`bar``

Note that the code formatting button does not help here.  It changes

```
foo `bar`
```

to

```
`foo `bar
```

`foo`bar

How about double back ticks?

````
``foo `bar```
````

``foo `bar```

Probably have to resort to `<code>`

```
<code>foo `bar`</code>
```

`foo bar`

with entities

```
<code>foo &#96;bar&#96;</code>
```

`` foo `bar` ``

with backslash

```
<code>foo \`bar\`</code>
```

`` foo `bar` ``

Answer (score 5):

#### Workaround:

This is a proper `backticked piece` without any gray background, or monotype font.

Instead of using `escaped backticks` which look ugly, you can use simple HTML entities, which will not be treated wrongly by the SO server parser. That's a workaround, not a fix of this bug, of course :)

Like so (`&#x60;` is the HTML Entity for the backtick):

```
This is a proper &#x60;backticked piece&#x60;
```

Inside post comments, you should use the "normal" way, as for some odd reason, HTML entities are written as text in comments:

```
use \`normal escape\` in comments, HTML entities don't work
```

Comment: @John: your edit removed `&#x60;` from the code block and replaced it with `\``, while that was really the whole clue of the workaround... I added that part back again.

Answer (score 2):

``backtick` testing

```
``foo` `  gives us
```

``foo

### EDIT:

If you don't want "foo" in monospace, you can use this:

```
`` `foo` ` ` gives us
```

`` `foo`

but then you get spaces around foo.

Comment: Hooray!  It doesn't make sense, but that's `<backtick><backtick>foo<backtick><space><backtick>`.

Comment: Try escaping backtics and backslashes...that's a nightmare.

Comment: `\\\``  - tic slash slash slash tic tic

Comment: To have lots of fun!! It beats working.

Comment: Nice! It'd be even nicer if we didn't have to resort to these horrible hacks though :)  Also, the workaround puts foo into monospace...

Comment: Jeez, you are a demanding one.  Fine, let's see if we can make it better...

Comment: \``\`` - desired is a literal non formatted backtic and a code formatted backtick. (slash tic tic slash tic tic)

Comment: That worked.

Comment: \``foo\`` - testing

Comment: still looks monospace to me...

Comment: @bdonlan: This is \`no monospace\` in the comment... this is `yes monospace` in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code :

> To include a literal backtick character within a code span, you can
>   use multiple backticks as the opening and closing delimiters:

```
``There is a literal backtick (`) here.`` which will produce this:

<p><code>There is a literal backtick (`) here.</code></p>
```

For example, if I can write this: `` foo`bar `` like this:

```
``foo`bar``
```