# Code escaping in comments eats backslashes

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

While I sometimes stumble over things where the normal formatter and the one in the comments disagree on the grave accent, such as:

```
* `abc`def
* `\`g`
```

Maybe it even is useful (though I can't see where inconsistency would be useful).

Unless it starts eating backslashes for (to me) unknown reasons, such as in:

```
* `copy F:\*.foo .`
```

Comment: `copy F:\*.foo .`

Comment: `copy F:\\*.foo .`

Comment: this was [recently fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74340/backslash-escaping-in-code-regions-in-comments/79218#79218)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash is used as an escape character here. Normally asterisks (*) indicate to *emphasis the following* part. A single asterisk does not do it, but the escape mechanism still works.

Comment: I still consider this a bug, though :-). Also I find it at least slightly unfortunate that while both questions/answers and comments use similar markup with pretty large differences in parsion, although that seems to be by design (still unfortunate).

Comment: I just wanted to clarify the (for you) unknown reasons ;)

Comment: Strange as it may seem, this escaping works in comments, but doesn't work in questions/answers. So, the "bug" seems to be the other way around. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12694/escaping-backticks-fails.

Comment: @Abel: Not necessarily. Posts use Markdown, while comments use some hackish attempt to integrate an extended subset of Markdown features. That's not the way UI consistency should go, though. Imho, at least.