# comment doesn't support multiple backticks code span

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, markdown, markdown-rendering

Quote from [markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code):

> To include a literal backtick character within a code span, you can use multiple backticks as the opening and closing delimiters:
>
> ```
> ``There is a literal backtick (`) here.``
> ```

stackvoverflow's comment system doesn't support this.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74340/backslash-escaping-in-code-regions-in-comments

Comment: `literal backtick \` here`

Comment: `` litetal backtick ` available ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is included in the improvements to comment markdown [as documented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981).

Answer (score 3):

Comments have very limited markdown support anyway.
You can already escape a backtick using a backslash, which seems more intuitive than multiple backticks:

```
`literal backtick \` here`
```

Comment: But this also means that you can't have a backslash as a last character in inline code in a comment.

Comment: @hendrik yes that is true, but I wonder how common that is?

Comment: @Jeff: Over at tex.sx [it's quite common any many have wondered what's wrong](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/posts/168/edit). One reason: We'd like to type `\`\\\`` in a comment to get a double backslash in inline code, which is a common TeX command. See also [this answer of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74340/backslash-escaping-in-code-regions-in-comments/77405#77405).