# How do you type a single backslash, code-formatted, in a comment?

Tags: support, comments, character-escaping

Is there a way to type something in a comment that renders like this?

> You'll need to escape it with a backslash - that is, the `\` character.

I've tried various combinations, but a single backslash formatted as code seems to be impossible.
Can this be fixed, or can I be enlightened please?

And to clarify: I expect this:

```
You'll need to escape it with a backslash - that is, the `\\` character.
```

to work properly, but it doesn't. Instead, one backslash escapes the `` ` `` and I'm left with a mess.

Comment: Testing...: `\ `

Comment: Try this: `＼`... `a\ `

Comment: Whoa! @Dennis did it! How?

Comment: @mini With a space, apparently.

Comment: possible duplicates: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11388/backslash-escaped-with-backticks-rendered-incorrectly-in-comments http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74340/backslash-escaping-in-code-regions-in-comments http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78499/comment-doesnt-support-multiple-backticks-code-span

Comment: Testing: ``\``  s

Comment: @chown: I swear, I couldn't find *any* of those questions in search! :P

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981 for some info on code spans in comments

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Ah, solved it:

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
``\``
```

which will produce *exactly* the comment you want without all the gymnastics, as seen in my test comment below this answer...

---

The problem is that the syntax you would expect

```
`\`
```

causes the closing backtick to be escaped by the backlash, which means no code formatting is applied (because you haven't properly closed the inline code block).

However, by inserting a space between the backslash and the backtick, you can cleverly disrupt this escaping behavior:

```
`\ `
```

This produces *almost* what you want, except that there's an ugly gap rendered after the backslash (see test comments elsewhere on this page).

So the next apparent hack would be to use a [Unicode zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_Width_Space), which will still disrupt the escaping behavior, but won't render as an ugly gap in your comment. Thus,

```
`\​`
```

will render exactly as you would expect it to.

Comment: Good idea, that's what I'll use for now. This is definitely looking like a bug, though.

Comment: More testing: ``\``

Comment: Dennis got the double-backticks answer first (by several minutes).

Comment: Oh no! That means he wins! I guess I'd better give back this [gold-plated unicorn statue](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qcuRI.jpg) that I won... @brock

Comment: Just saying, that your answer *LOOKS* like plagiarism. Veterans know that you probably worked it out in parallel, but it could all be cleared up with a simple attribution.

Answer (score 21):

```
`\`
```

doesn't work, because the backslash escapes the backtick.

Double backticks (``` `` ```) can also be used to delimit inline code blocks. This produces a single backslash:

```
``\``
```

Comment: `<code>` doesn't work in comments.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: I meant the markdown syntax for `<code>`. Fixed.

Comment: It actually doesn't ignore trailing whitespace in comments, sorry. I missed that. `\ ` See, there's a space.

Comment: @minitechη: Sadly, you're right. Testing: ``\`` OK, that worked.

Comment: "because the backslash escapes the backtick". Yeah, but then why is it rendered correctly in a Question/Answer? The parsing should be consistent in Comment as well as Question/Answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
Looks like [Dennis was first to probably the easiest answer to execute](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129705/148310), the double-backtick approach.

---

One way to do it is to use a space after:

```
`\ `
```

Another, without the pesky space is to use the ["Fullwidth Reverse Solidus"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff3c/index.htm)

```
`＼`
```

Comparison:

```
`\ ` versus
`＼`
```

On windows systems, you can often generate the full-width slash by holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and pressing <kbd>+</kbd> (numeric keypad), <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> (lower-case is fine).

Comment: Neither are really attractive solutions, though; awkward space or awkward backslash.

Comment: "Perfect"?  Hmm. It looks like a backslash on drugs, [at least on my machine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4PpgV.png).