# Code-higlighting a single backslash in comments doesn't work

Tags: bug, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you type a single backslash, code-formatted, in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129704/how-do-you-type-a-single-backslash-code-formatted-in-a-comment)

I was trying to get a `\` in a comment and couldn't do it... (To be clear, I mean a single backslash code-highlighted)

using apostrophes to demo...

- `'\'` resulted in ''
- `'\\'` resulted in  '\'

Either I'm missing something or this is a bug in the parsing... Is it possible with syntax I'm not familiar with?

Comment: It seems to work when you add an extra space at the end - `\ ` in comparison - \ `\ `

Comment: @Lix Thanks - You wouldn't believe how many comments have been posted and deleted on here in the last 5 mins lol. If you'd care to post that as an answer, I'll vote up. I'll leave this open a little while as I'd argue it should work without the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two ways I can see to get this to work.

#### 1. Extra space

Add an extra space between the backticks

```
`\ `
```

#### 2. Zero width character -

Add a zero width non printable character between the backticks

```
`\​`
```

Since this non printable character is...well.. non printable it's hard to give it to you here - you'll just have to trust me when I tell you it's between these brackets - `(​)`

Comment: **Method 1** - `\ `,  regular \

Comment: **Method 2** - `\​`,  regular \

Comment: Thanks - and again for demoing using a `\ ` to escape `\`` in code in a post - that's new to me too