# How do I escape backticks surrounding an inline code block?

Tags: support, markdown, inline-code, backtick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can the backtick character ` be included in code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code)

How do I do something like this:

```
`order`
```

But within a ``line`? <-- as you see over here I was able to get the starting backtick, but when I try to place on on the end,

it gets enclosed like `this`.

How do I get both backticks inline while still having the inline code block?

This is what happens when I try to escape the backticks with backslashes:
`\`this`\`

Comment: @TimPost -- These are **not** the same question. The one you call a duplicate is only asking about an ending backtick, I am asking about **surrounding** the word (or words) with backticks.

Comment: I re-opened, it may be worth noting that in your post.

Comment: @TimPost Thank you :-D! I fixed the title, I don't how I can be more descript than that.

Comment: It's close, but I don't think duplicate. The title edit and this comment trail should suffice :) Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah, but searching for "A single backtick in a code span" yields the nice [How can the backtick character ` be included in code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code/70679#70679), with a nice answer from Chris, which covers this too.

Comment: @Arjan ahhh, but if you notice in that post, **none** of the backticks are surrounding the code blocks.

Comment: Hehe, you're right! (Though it *does* quote the same Markdown help.)

Comment: Well gosh darnit this has to be a duplicate of _something_ (I kid, I kid!) I'm pretty sure this hasn't come up before, but ICBW.

Comment: @TimPost As could I. I see now that someone voted to close this as duplicate of the question Arjan linked....

Comment: Eh, I don't see why the post that Arjan linked to is insufficient. The second example from the Markdown help is exactly what this question is asking about.

Comment: @TimStone because [as I said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138912/how-do-i-escape-backticks-surrounding-an-inline-code-block#comment391123_138912), that example has **no** surrounding backticks.

Comment: What is this, if not exactly what you're asking about? `A backtick-delimited string in a code span: \`\` \`foo\` \`\``

Comment: @TimStone you see how that **did not work** in the comment?

Comment: Yes, because comment Markdown is different. Your post mentions comments a total of zero times. If you're interested, there's a [detailed explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981) of the differences.

Comment: Actually, reading [Chris' answer again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code/70679#70679), it *does* mention it. (And it should, as it quotes the same thing I did. So, both @Tim's are right, I feel. I can add the note about comments to that answer, but I cannot delete my answer as long as it's accepter...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Use spaces](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code):

> The backtick delimiters surrounding a code span may include spaces —
>   one after the opening, one before the closing. This allows you to place
>   literal backtick characters at the beginning or end of a code span:
>
> ```
> A single backtick in a code span: `` ` ``
>
> A backtick-delimited string in a code span: `` `foo` ``
> ```
>
> will produce:
>
> ```
> <p>A single backtick in a code span: <code>`</code></p>
>
> <p>A backtick-delimited string in a code span:  <code>`foo`</code></p>
> ```

Which on these sites indeed works just fine:

A single backtick in a code span: `` ` ``

A backtick-delimited string in a code span: `` `foo` ``

For comments:

```
Ah, in comments one does need to escape using a backslash? `\`yes\``.
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. cool. I never knew it was a `` `space` `` issue....

Comment: Hmmm it does **not** seem to be working in the comments....

Comment: [Indeed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78499/comment-doesnt-support-multiple-backticks-code-span)...

Comment: Ah, in comments one does need to escape using a backslash? `\`yes\``.

Comment: Hmmm how did you do that?   `\`This is a test\`` -- Cool ^_^

Comment: You might want to add the comment part to your answer.

Comment: Well, *that* was easier said than done ;-)

Comment: ` `test` `  `` `test` `` --  this doesn't seem to be working...  <code>`test`</code> Lies, all of it!

Comment: `\`Works for me\``, @Jason. That is: `\`\\`Works for me\\`\``.

Comment: `\`backslashes\`` -- perfect, got it. Thanks! I was confusing posts and comments and backslashes and double backticks and code tags and... well, it's working.

Comment: `a=\`echo "hello world"\`` - thanks - backslashes are what I'm looking for - upvoting this answer now

Comment: how to make ```{r}  this piece of code display in monocode mode? I am trying to write a Rmarkdown file to explain how the knitr package works to complie r code in the document. To just display ```{r},  \`\`\` {r} works. However, it is not in the monocode mode but plain text

Answer (score 2):

Use the backslash, it escapes everything: `this`.

This is part of the official MarkDown spec; see [Backslash escapes](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash).

If you want to use a backtick *inside* an inline code block, use `<code>` tags, in combination with the escape: `` `backtick` `` (source: `` <code>`backtick`</code> ``).

Comment: Yes, but then the `this` is not inside the code block anymore.

Comment: Updated to use `<code>` tags.

Comment: Ahhh, but your `<code>` idea won't work in comments.

Comment: Ahhh, but you didn't say it had to work in comments; backticks in comments are inside backticks *do* work with escapes (as you mentioned).