# Backticks Don't Work in Numbered Lists

Tags: discussion, markdown

I happened to be doing this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166347/how-do-i-use-ruby-for-shell-scripting/2392597#2392597) and I was going mad reading [the backtick post here on meta.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12694/escaping-backticks-fails)

This works fine

```
backtick this `this`
```

1. but this does not

   backtick this `this`

nor for bulleted lists

- nor this

  backtick this `this`

I'm not sure if this is a bug and surely it's been mentioned somewhere. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah-hah.  You need to increase the indent of the code block for each level of the list it's "under".  Indent 4 more spaces for each additional level:

```
example code
```

1. example 1

   ```
   example 1 code
   ```
2. example 2

   - example 2a

     ```
     example 2a code
     ```

ta-daaahh.  for reference, here's what's typed to show the above:

```
    example code

1. example 1

        example 1 code

2. example 2

  - example 2a

            example 2a code
```

Comment: Not sure why SO sorts the first answer last...? Anyway, thanks, that did it.

Comment: the sorting defaults to sorted-by-votes, with ties randomly sorted.  if you want a newest-first or oldest-first sort, use the tabs between the question and answer sections of this page.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this.  The one you want to use is to indent the code block 4 more spaces

1. indent the code example

   ```
   backtick this `this`
   ```

Also works for bulleted lists

- like this

  ```
  backtick this `this`
  ```

The other way to do it is to escape the ` character.  This is the option you want to use if you're *not* trying to format the line as code.

```
Escape the backtick like this \`
```

1. Using escaping like `this`

   or on the next line like `this`

Also works for bulleted lists

- like `this`

  or on the next line like `this`

Answer (score 1):

This works:

1. List item1

   ```
   Some code
   ```
2. List item2

   ```
   Some more code
   ```

Double indent.