# How can I write inline code ending in a backtick (`)?

Tags: support, markdown, inline-code

How can I write inline code (e.g. in a comment) ending in a backtick, without adding an extra space at the end?

I know that backticks can be included if the code is surrounded by double backticks, like so:

```
``context`fun``
```

But what if we want the last character of the code to be a backtick?

````
``context```  <-- this doesn't work because "```" doesn't close the code segment

``context` `` <-- this adds an extra space at the end
````

Use case: in Mathematica, [context names always end in a backtick](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Contexts.html).

Of course this is not a big deal, and we can live with that space at the end. I was curious if there was a way to do this. If this is not possible, I'll accept that as an answer.

Comment: Try using a backslash to escape the backtick: `\\`` It will then appear as a literal backtick.

Comment: @JasonPlank that does not work....

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA works for me: `context\``

Comment: @JasonPlank hehe idk what computer you are looking at :-P

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA viewed source because I don't always trust the highlighting. I see `<code>context\`</code>`. What do you see?

Comment: @JasonPlank oy... none of that works in the comments....

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA not sure what you mean by that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
``context` `` <-- this adds an extra space at the end
```

Actually, it doesn't. All characters have the same width inside `<code>`. It's just that the backtick is smaller than most characters, so **it seems like** there is a space at the end.

The following two have the same length:

`` context` ``

`contextA`

Comment: You might be right.  I realize the space might be an illusion because of the tiny size of \`. It's common to even move small glyphs like punctuation out towards the margin in professional typesetting to compensate for this illusion, isn't it?

Comment: You lost me at *professional typesetting*.

Comment: I just remembered this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_Margin_Alignment

Answer (score 4):

You have to cheat it:

`` context` ``

This was achieved by doing this:

```
<code>context&#96;</code>
```

I got the idea from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/29300/155556)

---

You can even do:

`` context` ``

Which was achieved by doing:

```
<code>context`</code>
```

<sup><sub>(thanks to Arjan in the comments)</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that we can use `<code>` instead of backticks!  It turns out I was wrong about the space at the end though ... it is stripped.  It is only an illusion that it appears.